# Add link to download CSV with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, canvas

I have added the below code for downloading CSV:

```
<%= form_tag(account_export_courses_list_path(@account), :method => :get) do |f| %>
  <a data-submit-form href="#" class="btn button-sidebar-wide"><i class="icon-export-content"></i> <%= t(:export_course_list_link, "Export Course List") %></a>
<% end %>
```

If I do inspect element then I am able to see the following:

```
<form method="get" action="/accounts/1/courses/export_list" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"></div>
      <a class="btn button-sidebar-wide" href="#" data-submit-form=""><i class="icon-export-content"></i> Export Course List</a>
</form>
```

And the following code is added in my controller:

```
  def export_courses_list
    puts "===-----------------------------------==="
    if authorized_action(@context, @current_user, :export_course_list)
      puts "-------"
      report = CsvService.new(@context.courses.active.order(:name, :created_at).all, {
        fields:[
          {attribute_name: "name", display_name: "Course Name"}, 
          {attribute_name: "course_code", display_name: "Course Code"},
          {attribute_name: "created_at", display_name: "Created Date"}
        ]
      })
      send_data report.to_csv, :filename => "Courses.csv"
    end
  end
```

My routes are as:

```
match 'courses/export_list' => 'accounts#export_courses_list', :as => :export_courses_list
```

After I click on the link, "Export Course List" I should be able to download the CSV. But I am not able to see any action getting performed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: In the logs nothing is coming after I click on the link

Comment: Either change your `a` tag to include the link you have specified as `form` action or replace this tag with `input` of type `submit`

Comment: If I add <%= link_to 'Export Course List', account_export_courses_list_path(@account.id) %>, then my logs are coming as: Started GET "/courses/export_list". 
After that it goes to courses_controller and there the paramers are coming wrong: CoursesController#show as HTML
[- dfd565d5-96c0-45c8-8384-48697b277b66]   Parameters: {"id"=>"export_list"}

Comment: I am checking the code in https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms repository

Comment: Are you doing `resources :courses` in routes?

Comment: It was already added in the application. https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/stable/config/routes.rb

Comment: just move this route `match 'courses/export_list' => 'accounts#export_courses_list', :as => :export_courses_list
` above `resources :course` and your `link_to` will work

Comment: Thanks. It now goes to that action if I add <%= link_to 'Export Course List', account_export_courses_list_path(@account.id) %> link.

Comment: I am going to post it as an answer. Please accept it if it yields the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this route

```
match 'courses/export_list' => 'accounts#export_courses_list', :as => :export_courses_list
```

above the following route

```
resources :courses
```

And then use it in your `link_to`. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

i think the action is performed.
If you don't sure, delete it and try click link again.
You can use `Rails.logger.info` instead `puts` to make sure log is written correctly.

**Update:**

*I thought you can download csv, but maybe not*

Your route will map url `/courses/export_list` to action `export_courses_list` in `AccountsController`

But the url in form is `/accounts/1/courses/export_list`, so action is not performed

you can change your routes to something like this

```
resources :accounts do
  member do
    get :export_courses_list, path: :export_list
  end
end
```

and use the `link` without `form` in view

```
<%= link_to export_courses_list_account_path(1), class: "btn button-sidebar-wide" do %>
  <i class="icon-export-content"></i> Export Course List
<% end %>
```